# discord api: hcaptcha "invalid-data" error

Tags: python, discord, captcha

im in process of making discord console client, and im stuck with this error:
discord wants me to complete captcha (e.g. `captcha-key: ['captcha-required']`), and gives me sitekey. i generate data:text/html page, with div.h-captcha and script tags as described in [docs](https://docs.hcaptcha.com/#add-the-hcaptcha-widget-to-your-webpage), and present it to user.
on page after trying to do the captcha it just says "invalid-data"

sample code:

```py
import requests
import base64
import json

api = "https://discord.com/api/v10"
login_info = json.loads(requests.post("%s/auth/login" % (api,), json={"login": input("mail: "), "password": getpass.getpass("password: ")}).content)

if "captcha_key" in login_info:
    html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hCaptcha</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Complete this captcha to continue, when done come back to MeltCord and press Enter:</h1>
        <div class="h-captcha" data-sitekey="%s"></div>
        <script src="https://js.hcaptcha.com/1/api.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>""" % (sitekey,)
    html = "data:text/html;base64," + base64.b64encode("".join([i.strip() for i in html.split("\n")]).encode()).decode()
    input("open this url in browser and compelete captcha:\n" + html)
```

googling didn't help ;(
thanks!